Snake game, How to make the snake to not move in opposite directions?
I'm making the snake game and now doing the part where if you move up you can't move directly down and so on...
I think I wrote the code well and it'll work but the jump points are too big and I tried moving the code to a procedure but I just can't think of a way where it works. I'd like if someone would tell me if I'm in the right direction.
The original code is this:
wasd:
    mov ah, 1h
    int 16h
    jnz newDir ;Check if there's something in the buffer, if not continue
    
    call delay
   
    cmp [dir], 'q'
    jz exit
    cmp [dir], 'a'
    jz a
    cmp [dir], 's'
    jz s
    cmp [dir], 'd'
    jz d
    cmp [dir], 'w'
    jz w
    cmp [dir], 'r'
    jz restart
    
;recive new direction
newDir:
    mov ah, 0h
    int 16h
    mov [dir], al ;Change direction
    jmp wasd  
w:
    call up
    jmp wasd
s:
    call down
    jmp wasd    
a:
    call left
    jmp wasd
d:
    call right
    jmp wasd
    
exit:

the new one is this:
    mov ah, 1h
    int 16h
    jnz newDir ;Check if there's something in the buffer, if not continue
    
    call delay
   
    cmp [dir], 'q'
    jz exit
    cmp [dir], 'a'
    jz a
    cmp [dir], 's'
    jz s
    cmp [dir], 'd'
    jz d
    cmp [dir], 'w'
    jz w
    cmp [dir], 'r'
    jz restart
    
;recive new direction
newDir:
    mov ah, 0h
    int 16h
    
    push al
    mov di, offset dir
    push di
    call checkDir
    
    cmp [dir], a
    jz checkA
    
    cmp [dir], s
    jz checkS
    
    cmp [dir], d
    jz checkD
    
    cmp [dir], w
    jz checkW
    
    mov [dir], al ;Change direction
    jmp wasd 
w:
    call up
    jmp wasd
s:
    call down
    jmp wasd    
a:
    call left
    jmp wasd
d:
    call right
    jmp wasd
    
checkA:
    cmp al, d
    jz wasd
    jmp a
    
checkS:
    cmp al, w
    jz wasd
    jmp s
    
checkD:
    cmp al, a
    jz wasd
    jmp d
    
checkW:
    cmp al, s
    jz wasd
    jmp w
    
exit:

the procedure I have so far is this:
;al - 6
;dir - 4
;IP
;bp
    push bp
    mov bp, sp
    push di
    push al
    push bx
    
    mov di, [bp+4]
    mov di, [di]
    mov al, [bp+6]
    jmp checkAll
    
checkA:
    cmp al, d
    jz finCheck
    jmp a
    
checkS:
    cmp al, w
    jz finCheck
    jmp s
    
checkD:
    cmp al, a
    jz finCheck
    jmp d
    
checkW:
    cmp al, s
    jz finCheck
    mov 

checkAll:
    cmp di, a
    jz checkA
    
    cmp di, s
    jz checkS
    
    cmp di, d
    jz checkD
    
    cmp di, w
    jz checkW
    
finCheck:
    pop bx
    pop al
    pop di
    pop bp
 ret
endp checkDir

*I know the jmp a/s/d/w is worng

Instead of doing body collision detection and opposite sides separately, I made only a body collision detection procedure and it also detects if you try moving in opposite direction.
proc bodyCollision
;amount - 6
;SPL - 4
;IP
;bp
    push bp
    mov bp, sp
    push di
    push bx
    push si
    push ax
    push cx
    
    mov di, [bp+4]
    mov bx, [bp+6]
    mov cx, [bx] ;cx = amount
    xor ax, ax ;count
    mov si, di ;si = offset
    mov di, [di] ;di = head
    
checkBC:
    cmp cx, ax
    jz finCheck
    inc ax
    add si, 2
    mov bx, [si] ;bx = current Check
    cmp di, bx
    jnz checkBC
    call endGame
    
finCheck:
    pop cx
    pop ax
    pop si
    pop bx
    pop di
    pop bp
 ret 4
endp bodyCollision

That's where I call it:
proc up ;Makes the snake move one step up
;Recives SPL, apple location & snake parts amount, returns new SPL, apple location & snake parts amount
;bodyCollision - 14
;direction - 12
;borderCheck - 10
;amount - 8
;apple - 6
;SPL - 4
;IP
;bp...
    push bp ;blackBox
    mov bp, sp
    push di
    push ax
    push bx
    
    mov di, [bp+4]
    mov di, [di]
    cmp di, 160
    jnb noDieUp
    call endGame
    
noDieUp:
;Give to bodyCollision SPL (snake's Part's Locations) and amount
    mov di, [bp+8]
    push di
    mov di, [bp+4]
    push di
    call bodyCollision
...

(In procedures up/down/left & right)
I also changed the code to the original:
;recive new direction
newDir:
    mov ah, 0h
    int 16h
    mov [dir], al ;Change direction
    jmp wasd  
w:
    call up
    jmp wasd
s:
    call down
    jmp wasd    
a:
    call left
    jmp wasd
d:
    call right
    jmp wasd
    
exit:

